# Freeglut 64 bit program linking errors

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, freeglut

I'm trying to compile a 64 bit version of an OpenGL C++ program using freeglut. I followed the exact instructions on [this website](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/) to set up freeglut with MinGW. I have the header files in `C:\MinGW\include\GL`, I have the 32 bit libraries in `C:\MinGW\lib` and 64 bit libraries in `C:\MinGW\lib\x64`, and I have the 64 bit `freeglut.dll` in my project directory. However, even the simplest of OpenGL programs don't link successfully...

My code is minimal:

```
// test.cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
}
```

And I compile it with the exact commands given on the readme/on the website:

```
g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp -I"C:\MinGW\include"
g++ -o test.exe test.o -L"C:\MinGW\lib\x64" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

(except of course I changed the directories and changed gcc to g++)

The compile runs fine, but linking throws these error messages:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried to change `-lopengl32` in the command to `-lopengl64` and `-lopengl`, but the linker couldn't find those libraries.

Comment: The original mingw is 32-bit only. Use a 64bit version like M.M suggested

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 mingw-w64 has 32bit and 64-bit versions. It added 64-bit support, without removing 32-bit

Comment: @M.M like i said the _origional_ mingw was 32bit only while your suggestion of mjngw-w64 is completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your specific case, but another approach would be to use mingw-w64, with MSYS2 as a package manager. The old mingw.org project is not well maintained, unlike mingw-w64 and the MSYS2 package database.  There is probably some mismatch between how your precompiled binaries were built and the compiler you are currently using.

On my system I compiled your code with `g++ -o gl gl.cpp -lfreeglut` and it worked first time .

[How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Then use `pacman -Ss glut` to find the freeglut package.

Comment: So you're saying mingw itself was the problem? Thanks I'll try it out.